# Finding the neighbors of all map coordinates

Tags: python, performance, numpy, set

I need help optimizing my code. Here is the dastardly function in question.

```
def FindAllNeighborCoords(cardinal_neighbor_array, principle_neighbor_array, width, height):

    # Loop through every coordinate on the map.
    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):

            # These if checks make sure the coordinate is in the map.
            if x - 1 >= 0:
                cardinal_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y))
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y))

            if y - 1 >= 0:
                cardinal_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x, y - 1))
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x, y - 1))

            if y + 1 < height:
                cardinal_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x, y + 1))
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x, y + 1))

            if x + 1 < width:
                cardinal_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x + 1, y))
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x + 1, y))

            if x - 1 >= 0 and y - 1 >= 0:
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y - 1))

            if x - 1 >= 0 and y + 1 < height:
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y + 1))

            if x + 1 < width and y - 1 >= 0:
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x + 1, y - 1))

            if x + 1 < width and y + 1 < height:
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x + 1, y + 1))

print cardinal_neighbor_array[20, 20]
set([20, 21), (21, 20), (19, 20), (20, 19)])
```

This function loops through everyone coordinate on the map, finds that neighbors surrounding neighbor coordinates and saves them to a set. It searches for two neighbor types - cardinal and principal. Or, 4 and 8. Each set is placed in a 2D array. I can then grab the neighbors of a coordinate by doing something like cardinal_array[0, 0] which will return a set of coordinates. I hope that makes sense! I use neighbors a TON in my project so it's faster to find and store them all once rather than repeatedly look them up. Enormous parts of my engine use these neighbor sets so I'd rather speed up how it currently works than making any major changes. The sets are comprised of tuples containing the (x, y) coordinates of each neighbor. The tuple thing can be changed if you have a better solution. This function is called once during map generation and its the slowest by far.

[image: Here's a image of it's profiling results if that might help.]

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious things to do.  All statements like `if x - 1 >= 0` should be replaced by `if x > 0` because that saves an addition.  And once you've determined the truth value of an expression like `x > 0`, use that result if you need it again later. For example:

```
        if x > 0:
            cardinal_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y))
            principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y))
            if y > 0:
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y - 1))
            if y < height-1:
                principle_neighbor_array[x, y].add((x - 1, y + 1))
```

You can improve that last `if` statement above: declare a variable `hm1 = height-1` before your first loop begins, and use that variable inside the loop whenever necessary.  Otherwise height-1 is computed over and over again.  Python doesn't optimize this sort of thing for you.

These are relatively minor.  The big problem I see is that you are doing 12 array lookups in your inner loop.  Every expression like `principle_neighbor_array[x, y]` involves a lookup into a two-dimensional array, which must be costly.  So at the top of your inner loop, declare two local variables that are synonyms for the sets you're going to work with:

```
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        cardinal_set = cardinal_neighbor_array[x, y]
        principle_set = principle_neighbor_array[x, y]
```

Rewrite all the code inside the loop to use these two sets.  You save ten array lookups for each iteration.

I don't know how much this will help, but it's easy to do and will certainly improve things.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing 2x as many operations as required.

If A is a neighbor of B then clearly B is a neighbor of A.

Rather than checking all 4 or 8 directions, just check half of them, e.g. just North, Northeast, East, and Southeast, and when you find a hit record both the (A, B) and (B, A) pairings at the same time.